# Is Web.config or App.config keys are case insensitive?

Tags: c#, .net

I am accessing the key from App.config in the class. If I give the key irrespective of case I am able to access its value.

I have checked that I am not doing ToLower() anywhere.

```
//The below is the key in App.config
<add key="Timezone_Minutes" value="+100"/>

//Accessing this key in class
 private static readonly string timezoneMinutes = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["TIMEZONE_MINUTES"];
```

I am getting the value +100 in timezoneMinutes. The key given in App.config is Timezone_Minutes, but accessing in class is TIMEZONE_MINUTES. But still I get the value. Is it case insensitive. I googled, but didn't get the proper answer.

Comment: If you are getting the value, then it clearly isn't case sensitive.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But is it the way expected ? Or internally is there any dll which is handling this that I am not sure of.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As per [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection?view=netframework-4.8) (for the type returned by [`AppSettings`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.configuration.configurationsettings.appsettings?view=netframework-4.8)):

> The default comparer is a CaseInsensitiveComparer that uses the
>   conventions of the invariant culture; that is, key comparisons are
>   case-insensitive by default.

This is consistent with the behaviour you are seeing.